# NaN in multiplication

Tags: javascript

I am trying this code, but i am getting NaN

```
a = unidade.val();
b = unitario.val();
//alert(a);5
//alert(b);50,00
$(total).val(a * b); //NaN
```

Why? because is a `int*float`?

Comment: Javascript only has numbers. No int and float.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to parse the strings before you multiply as [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) always returns a string and `"50,00"` can't be converted automatically to a number.

`parseFloat("50,1")` gives you `50`. If the comma here is the decimal separator, you have to replace it with a dot.

So you probably need

```
a = parseFloat(unidade.val().replace(",", ".");
b = parseFloat(unitario.val().replace(",", ".");
```

**EDIT :**

if you want to allow numbers formatted like `2.500,00`, then I propose this code :

```
function vf(str) {
   return parseFloat(str.replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
}
a = vf(unidade.val());
b = vf(unitario.val());
```

But it's dangereous if you have users who prefer (or expect) the American notation. I'd probably stick to the American notation and show an error if the field contains a comma.

Note that HTML5 proposes `<input type=number>` which forces the user to type number and let you get numbers directly. See [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html).

Comment: the problem is if i have something like this `2*2.500,00=5` and should be `5.000,00`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you get strings from `val()` function.

You can use `Number`, or `parseInt`, or `parseFloat` to cast types

```
$(total).val(Number(a) * Number(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the strings before you multiply!

Note:
If the operands are numbers, regular arithmetic multiply is performed, meaning that two positives or two negatives equal a positive, whereas operands with different signs yield a negative. If the result is too high or too low, the result is either Infinity or –Infinity.

If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN.

If Infinity is multiplied by 0, the result is NaN.

If Infinity is multiplied by any number other than 0, the result is either Infinity or –Infinity, depending on the sign of the second operand.

If Infinity is multiplied by Infinity, the result is Infinity.